# How to fix given row to avoid delete using .remove function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I created a table where in can add and remove dynamically. I just have a little problem where it comes to deleting a row. I want my first row to be fixed because when I used `remove()` it deletes the row that I given.

Table:

```
<div class = "col-md-12">

    <table class = "table" id = "customFields">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Stock No.</th>
                <th>Unit</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary" id = "addMore">+ Add</button>
    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger" id = "removeRow">- Remove</button>

</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#addMore").click(function ()
        {
            $("#customFields").append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td></tr>');
        });

        $("#removeRow").click(function()
        {
            $('#customFields td:last').remove();
        });
    });

</script>
```

I used `last` function to delete the row but this only delete one textfield. How can I delete this by 4? Any help would appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` represents the row and `td` represent the row's single cell.

You should read and explore about [**HTML tables**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_tables.htm)

```
 $('#customFields tr:last').remove();
```

[**Working Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/w6onceos/2/)

and to keep first row always , Count the tr length , and do the delete operation

```
 $("#removeRow").click(function()
        {   if($('#customFields tbody tr').length== 1){

            // only one row left
             alert("Cant delete first row")
        }else
        {
        $('#customFields tr:last').remove();
        }

        });
```

And Since your `thead` has a `tr` too . So delete using this selection

```
$('#customFields tbody tr:last').remove();
```

it will delete `tr` from `tbody` only

Comment: This work! But my first row deleted? How can I make my first row undeleted?

Comment: @Francisunoxx : click on working demo in my answer , It works perfect

Comment: @Francisunoxx : Do you want  to keep the tr always undeleted ?

Comment: Yes exactly because when I hit the remove button twice or thrice it removes the first row that I want to be undeleted also the <th> deleted too.

Comment: I see what you did in there you just set the length :p You're great!

Comment: you are great too !!

Answer (score 1):

you should select last row, instead of last table data(td). I mean in  `$('#customFields td:last').remove();` statement, instead of using td:last , please use tr:last.

i fixed it in this [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/filenifivu/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: This delete's the first row and also the <th>